# Xamarin Forms - Map CustomImagePin with text label right below

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.android

Hi StackOverflow Community.

I am struggling to add a text label along with a custom image pin in Xamarin forms custom map project.

Currently, i followed up the official Xamarin forms the documentation of how to implement custom pins on the map.

But want to extend a little more this functionality as showing also a label right below the pin is Critical for the application.

I wasn't lucky to find any custom solution for this

Could you please assist?

Below you can find the website solution I am using with google maps. Something like that needs to be created also for the Xamarin app

[image]

Comment: a label right below the pin? could you attach a illustration to describe your requirement, I think it will be more intuitive.

Comment: I want to show fuel prices of gas stations within user's local area (<5km). I did this for my website using google maps. But it seems to be hard to embed with Xamarin forms. Please check the screenshot of my website. This is what I need to do also for xamain.

Comment: Have you got any solution to your problem